# Error: Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#

When typing the following code, the console opens and I can input a value but when I press a key the .NET crashes and the console shuts down

I've tried to type only "text" + input and $ at the start of "text"

```
using System;

namespace Programmeren1Week2
{
    class Program
    {
        const double BTW = 0.21;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Geef prijs:");
            Console.ReadLine();

            double invoer = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            double metBTW = invoer * BTW;

            Console.WriteLine($"De prijs is {0}:" + invoer, "de btw is {1}:" + BTW, "Totaalprijs is {2}: " + metBTW);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have two ReadLine() calls.  Are you perhaps typing the value during the first one (the result of which is not being stored), and then just hitting enter on the 2nd?  If so, that would cause the error you are getting.

Comment: ....that is., try removing the first  "Console.ReadLine();"  statement.  It seems out of place, and might be tripping you up.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to reproduce your issue by passing in a text value where you ask for input. If by

> I've tried to type only "text" + input and $ at the start of "text"

You mean you are typing "text" when prompted for input, that's your problem.

Your `invoer` variable is a double, so it cannot accept strings as input. Try inputting a numerical value, and see if that fixes your problem.

---

That issue aside, there is one other thing that needs fixing.

As a few others have pointed out, you are formatting your string incorrectly. This will cause an issue if you fix your original error. To fix this, change that line to be:

```
Console.WriteLine($"The prize is {invoer}, the VAT is {BTW}: Total price is {metBTW}: ");
```

This should produce a functioning program.

Comment: I think you're right here.  Looking at the edit history, OP's question appears to be a "homework question".  Likely case of copying in some code and trying to run it without understanding what is being taught :-)   have an upvote!

Comment: Most likely. Looks like a program to calculate tax. 

Still, we've all been here at one point, right?

Comment: Yes its homework! Not copying though, I really want to learn. I have still some trouble understanding how to fix certain problems but its only my first week in Computer Science. Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably that you are entering a string that cannot be parsed to a double in your ReadLine call.

If propose this alternative solution to handle this issue.

```
 Console.WriteLine("Geef prijs:");


  if(double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out double invoer))
  {

   double metBTW = invoer * BTW;

   Console.WriteLine($"De prijs is : {invoer} , de btw is : {BTW} , otaalprijs is : {metBTW}");

   Console.ReadKey();

}
else 
{
  Console.WriteLine("Bad input");
}
```

Comment: that's true, but your answer is a red herring.  the title says clearly what the problem is  "Input string was not in a correct format."   the misuse of string interpolation is not causing that exception.   try reproducing the error before throwing together an answer.

Comment: @RichardII You are correct that this is not the cause of the error described by OP, but It is a genuine issue in the code that needs fixing. As given, the code will not display what OP wants, even if the current issue is fixed.

Comment: then the answerer should have put THIS in a comment on the question.  It is NOT an answer to the question.    Alternatively, he could have answered the actual question, and then added a side remark.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Parse use TryParse. (It returns true for valid values, and false for invalid values.)  Use it like this:

```
double number;
if (Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number))
{  
   // normal flow
}
 else
{
   // bad input (not a double, request another input)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

> Console.WriteLine(String.Format("De prijs is {0}: de btw is {1}: Totaalprijs is {2}: ", invoer, BTW, metBTW));

Or

This

> Console.WriteLine($"De prijs is {invoer}: de btw is {BTW}:
>   Totaalprijs is {metBTW}: " );

Comment: Misuse of string interpolation is not causing the exception shown in the title.  Before throwing together an answer, try to reproduce the error.